# "Detected problems with API-compatibility"

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, teechart

I am using the current Delphi 10.3 release along with the current TeeChart FMX 2018.26 release. The Android device is a onePlus 6T with Android 9. Unfortunately, a "detected problems with API-compatibility" is currently being shown. I have used a completely new project with only a simple chart of TeeChart, so I can rule out other incompatibilities.

Is there any usable solution for this?

http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=2134

Comment: Could you please edit the question adding a screenshot or the complete error message?

Comment: I see you reported the same to bugzilla. I've added the link to your question

Comment: "Is there any usable solution for this?" As far as I'm aware you'll receive that message with just a blank app on Android 9.

Answer (score 7):

Referencing to docs: In Android P, this dialog showing

> Detected problems with API compatibility

**Why this dialog is being shown?**

**Reason**: Your code hit the

> dark greylist

What are dark greylist apis? 
Such apis that are not permissible to call by other apps, In my case i was using the startSoftAp method that was dark grey listed. Removing that call vanished the dialog.

How will you find?

In your `logcat -> verbose -> Search("Accessing hidden")`

LOGCAT RESULT

Accessing hidden method:Landroid/net/wifi/WifiManager:startSoftAp(Landroid/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration;)Z (dark greylist, reflection)